# How can I move Sphinx realtime index to another server?

Tags: sphinx

What is the best method to transfer Sphinx real time index from one machine to another. If it was disk index, I could just move the database and re-index it again, but the index is RT. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Stop searchd on source gracefully.  (ie `searchd --stopwait`, rather than just forceibly killing it, or crashing etc)
- Copy /var/folder/indexname* to destination machine. (where using the prefix as noted in the index definition)
- Copy the index definition to the destination.
- Start up searchd on destination.

Most likly to work successfully if both machines have the same version of sphinx installed.

Comment: Wow that simple? I've met that solution somewhere, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks, barryhunter!

Comment: pretty much yes. As long as searchd was shutdown cleanly all the files should be fine. In particular the RAM chunk is written to disk. If searchd wasnt shutdown, then the binlog may be needed to recover data, it will be much harder to transfer if pending changes in binlog.